# How to use android.R.layout?

Tags: android

In my mobile application i am extending ListActivity at one point. i want to have each of the list items to have a textview and a checkbox. i do not want to use custom layout. How do i use the default android layouts and achieve the same?
The entries for the text view at stored in an Array so i am using SimpleArrayAdapter. i can also use SimpleCursorAdapter if need be.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey some code of where you have got up to so far would engage more people to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice for layout id.

this will give you a check box and your desired string from the adapter in all the list items.

Comment: but how do i get list of all the items the user has clicked?

Comment: could you also give me the code for setting the adapter for the listview, i mean i need to set the id of the textbox in android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice which will be allocated the values from my array.....